# Selenium Python: StaleElementReferenceException with a twist

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm running into the infamous StaleElementReferceExeption error with selenium. I've checked previous questions on the subject, and the common solution is to add and implicit.wait, explicit.wait, or time.sleep to give the website time to load. I've tried this, but I am still experiencing an error. Can anyone tell what the issue is

Here is my code:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.overline-productName")


    time.sleep(2)
    #finds pricing data of links on page
    link_count = 0
    for element in links:

        links[link_count].click()
        cents = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.cents")
        dollar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.dollar")
        text_price = dollar.text + "." + cents.text
        price = float(text_price)
        print(price)
        print(link_count)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
        link_count = link_count + 1
        time.sleep(5)
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Update the question with the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ and the relevant _HTML_

Comment: this has nothing to do with waiting at all.  it is simply programmer error.. you are triggering navigation which causes all elements to go stale and then expecting them to not be stale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing your links in a list. The second you follow a link to another page, that set of links is stale. So the next iteration in your loop will attempt to click a stale link from the list.

Even if you go back in history as you do later, that original element reference is gone.

Your best bet is to loop through based on index, and find the links each time you return to the page.